# "unexpected end of input" when Jinja templating used to provide multiple parameters to onclick function

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I'm trying to run a js function using parameters passed into the template via jinja, where item contains strings as follows:

```
item.id = 'item1'
item.indicator = 'yes' #or no
```

Template code:

```
{% for item in items %}
        <!--The error is thrown by the line directly below!-->
        <div class='qitem' id='{{item.id}}' onclick = change_background('{{item.indicator}}', '{{item.id}}')></div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function change_background(indicator, id){
    if (indicator == 'yes'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.background='lightgreen';
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.background='pink';
</script>
```

In the culpable line in my code, `'{{item.indicator}}'` is red, and the first ' is underlined in vscode.

The code works despite this, if only ONE argument it used as follows:
`change_background('{{item.indicator}}')` (with corresponding function adjusted accordingly), but does not work if I try to use two arguments.

The order of the arguments doesn't seem to matter. Neither does using `"{{}}"` instead of `'{{}}'`.

Additionally, if I attempt to run two functions onclick:
`<div class='qitem' id='{{item.id}}' onclick = make_green('{{item.id}}'); increment_click('{{item.indicator}}')>`

only the first executes, and the second is ignored without any errors being thrown!

I've searched on here and elsewhere. I don't really want to jsonify the data I pass in to the template. I feel as though there's a nuance I'm missing when using jinja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nuance here is simply your use of JavaScript in HTML.

You'll need

```
onclick="change_background('{{item.indicator}}', '{{item.id}}')"
```

instead of

```
onclick = change_background('{{item.indicator}}', '{{item.id}}')>
```

to properly wrap the JavaScript segment in quotes.

> Additionally, if I attempt to run two functions onclick:
>
> ```
> <div class='qitem' id='{{item.id}}' onclick = > make_green('{{item.id}}'); increment_click('{{item.indicator}}')>
> ```

Same thing here.

```
onclick="make_green('{{item.id}}');increment_click('{{item.indicator}}')"
```

Comment: That'll teach me to venture to the front end... thanks very much, that was it!